# OpenGL Qt 4.8 Render to texture floating point

Tags: c++, opengl, qt4.8

so i'm working on a project based on Qt 4.8 so when using OpenGL i have to go through the QGL stuff.

My goal is to write data on a floating point texture to perform per pixel picking (3 values are written on each pixel 2 integers and a float value).

so i used the QGLFramebufferObject and the offscreen rendering is happening, but i'm having issues retrieving my data. The first thing i looked into is specifying the internal format for the FBO , but when trying to use the right format i need GL_RGB32F the compiler can't find it , i checked the context and it is a 3.1 core profile so it should be there. My second problem is with the clamping when reading back information from the buffer it is normalized so i know i have to disable the clamping of values with glClampColorARB but compiler doesn't find it neither.

So i guess my question is how do i load what's missing so i can find my constant for the internal format and the clamping function.

Thanks

Comment: This is only a side note totally unrealted to the issue, but: " checked the context and it is a 3.1 core profile " No, it is not. That version _doesn't even exist_. Core profile was introduced with GL 3.2, so no idea what context version you have...

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you are compiling with an older OpenGL header file. On MS Windows the default GL/gl.h is for something like version 1.1 :-(

AFAIK the Qt headers for the GL related classes don't include everything in OpenGL, just the minimum to work. You should get your own copy of glcorearb.h, say from www.opengl.org, and include that in your source code.

(What you are attempting can be done: I have a Linux/MSWin/Mac program built with Qt 4.8.6 that renders to offscreen floating point buffers. I'd offer code but I created the framebuffer directly with OpenGL calls rather than using the Qt class.)

Comment: thanks man , i will check the header solution first, i have considered doing every thing in native OpenGL calls, so that would be the next step i'll keep the post updated !